# How to delay the form submission using server actions with Nextjs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following Form component which receives the input fields as a children prop:

```
  return (
    <form action={dispatch} className="w-full flex" autoComplete="off">
      <div className={`${fieldSpacing} ${maxWidthClass} w-full`}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
          if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            const isCustomComponent = typeof child.type !== "string";
            const childProps = isCustomComponent
              ? {
                  ...child.props,
                  errors: errors[child.props.name],
                  formState,
                }
              : {
                  ...child.props,
                };
            return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
          }
          return child;
        })}

        {notification && <Notification {...notification} />}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

That currently works well but I need to delay the submission to make some animations in the form before the data is sent to the server. Then I've modified the code to:

```
  const handleAction = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    dispatch(formData);
  };

  return (
    <form
      //action={dispatch}
      onSubmit={handleAction}
      className="w-full flex"
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div className={`${fieldSpacing} ${maxWidthClass} w-full`}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
          if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            const isCustomComponent = typeof child.type !== "string";
            const childProps = isCustomComponent
              ? {
                  ...child.props,
                  errors: errors[child.props.name],
                  formState,
                }
              : {
                  ...child.props,
                };
            return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
          }
          return child;
        })}

        {notification && <Notification {...notification} />}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

This also works, sending the data to the server but the problem is that I cannot automatically get the `pending` state (from `useFormStatus`) on my submit button component anymore (it works using the action in the first version of the code).

This is my button component (submit):

```
const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, bgColor, href, ...buttonProps }) => {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  const bgColorClass =
    bgColor === "purple"
      ? "bg-purple-900 hover:bg-purple-950 border-purple-950 disabled:bg-purple-950 disabled:border-purple-950"
      : "bg-indigo-800 hover:bg-indigo-900 border-indigo-900 disabled:bg-indigo-900 disabled:border-indigo-900";

  const isSubmitLoading = buttonProps.type === "submit" && pending;

  // Text animation variants
  const textVariants = {
    initial: { y: 0, opacity: 1 },
    hidden: { y: -20, opacity: 0 },
  };

  // Spinner animation variants
  const spinnerVariants = {
    initial: { y: 20, opacity: 0 },
    visible: { y: 0, opacity: 1 },
  };

  const ButtonContent = (
    <>
      {!isSubmitLoading && (
        <motion.div
          initial="initial"
          animate={isSubmitLoading ? "hidden" : "initial"}
          variants={textVariants}
          transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
        >
          {title}
        </motion.div>
      )}

      {isSubmitLoading && (
        <motion.div
          initial="initial"
          animate={isSubmitLoading ? "visible" : "hidden"}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          variants={spinnerVariants}
          transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
        >
          <LiaSpinnerSolid className="animate-spin text-xl" />
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </>
  );

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      {href ? (
        <Link
          href={href}
          className={`inline-flex items-center justify-center border rounded-md py-2 px-4 text-sm font-bold text-gray-100 shadow-sm transition-all duration-200 w-full uppercase ${bgColorClass}`}
        >
          {ButtonContent}
        </Link>
      ) : (
        <button
          {...buttonProps}
          className={`inline-flex items-center justify-center border rounded-md py-2 px-4 text-sm font-bold text-gray-100 shadow-sm transition-all duration-200 w-full uppercase disabled:cursor-not-allowed ${bgColorClass}`}
          disabled={buttonProps.disabled || pending}
        >
          {ButtonContent}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I fix it? Is the only option to create a global state for this? I'd like to get the this to work using the `pending` state if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: it is but the issue here is that using onSubmit instead of action, I don't get the pending state from useFormStatus. It stops working (it's always false)